# Qt input audio measuring

Tags: c++, qt, audio, signal-processing, volume

I want to measure the level of input volume in peak or decibel or other things.I just want to measure it and detect the loudness.I have this code but it does not detect continuously.**It just detect the level at the beginning and after, the level begins to reduce.**
Related parts of header file:

```cpp
  Q_INVOKABLE void start();
  Q_INVOKABLE void stop();
  std::shared_ptr<QAudioInput> source;
  QIODevice *device;
  QAudioFormat format;
  int peak = 0, n;
  int16_t v;
```

C++ file:

```cpp
#include "Bot.h"

void Bot::start() {
  format.setByteOrder(QAudioFormat::LittleEndian);
  format.setChannelCount(2);
  format.setCodec("audio/pcm");
  format.setSampleRate(8000);
  format.setSampleSize(16);
  format.setSampleType(QAudioFormat::SignedInt);
  source = std::shared_ptr<QAudioInput>(new QAudioInput(format));
  device = source->start();
  connect(device, SIGNAL(readyRead()), this, SLOT(onReadyRead()));
}

void Bot::stop() {
  source = nullptr;
  device = nullptr;
  peak = 0;
  emit volumeChanged(peak);
}

void Bot::onReadyRead() {
  peak = 0;
  n = source->bytesReady();
  n /= 2;
  if (n >= 80) {
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
      v = 0;
      device->read((char *)&v, 2);
      if (v < 0) {
        v = -v;
      }
      if (peak < v) {
        peak = v;
      }
    }
    peak = peak * 100 / 32768;
    if (peak < 0) {
      peak = 0;
    }
    emit volumeChanged(peak);
  }
}
```

Comment: that is because `readyRead() is not emitted recursively`

Comment: have a look at this example https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtmultimedia-multimedia-audioinput-example.html, which demonstrates what you are looking for.